# f-string with float formatting in list-comprehension

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension, python-3.6, number-formatting

The `[f'str']` for string formatting was recently introduced in python 3.6. [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). I'm trying to compare the `.format()` and `f'{expr}` methods.

```
 f ' <text> { <expression> <optional !s, !r, or !a> <optional : format specifier> } <text> ... '
```

Below is a list comprehension that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius.

Using the `.format()` method it prints the results as float to two decimal points and adds the string Celsius:

```
Fahrenheit = [32, 60, 102]

F_to_C = ['{:.2f} Celsius'.format((x - 32) * (5/9)) for x in Fahrenheit]

print(F_to_C)

# output ['0.00 Celsius', '15.56 Celsius', '38.89 Celsius']
```

I'm trying to replicate the above using the `f'{expr}` method:

```
print(f'{[((x - 32) * (5/9)) for x in Fahrenheit]}')  # This prints the float numbers without formatting 

# output: [0.0, 15.555555555555557, 38.88888888888889]
# need instead: ['0.00 Celsius', '15.56 Celsius', '38.89 Celsius']
```

Formatting the float in `f'str'` can be achieved:

```
n = 10

print(f'{n:.2f} Celsius') # prints 10.00 Celsius
```

Trying to implement that into the list comprehension:

```
print(f'{[((x - 32) * (5/9)) for x in Fahrenheit]:.2f}') # This will produce a TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Is it possible to achieve the same output as was done above using the `.format()` method using `f'str'`?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to do the list comprehension *inside* the f-string? You didn't do that for the `.format()` version. Looks like you know what how to do it, you just need to not screw it up.

Comment: If I do it outside the list comp it won't modify each of the elements accordingly. I'm trying to see what type of *expr* can be used in `f'str'`.

Comment: You *are* doing it outside the list comp. And what does "won't modify each of the elements accordingly" mean?

Comment: I need it to iteratively modify each element in the list as was done using `.format()` Trying to figure out how to take this output `[0.0, 15.555555555555557, 38.88888888888889]` to `['0.00 Celsius', '15.56 Celsius', '38.89 Celsius']` with `f'str'` using a list comprehension.

Comment: Again: You've already proven that you already know how to do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to put the f-string inside the comprehension:

```
[f'{((x - 32) * (5/9)):.2f} Celsius' for x in Fahrenheit]
# ['0.00 Celsius', '15.56 Celsius', '38.89 Celsius']
```

Comment: Note: I just ran into a bug (or is it a feature) which means its not allowed to have a space after the formatting operation: `f'{0.3456:.2f}'` << works | `f'{ 0.3456:.2f }'` does not work!